# dynamically create columns in df python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a df consisted of 3 columns and 5 rows. I want to create new columns into the df. Although the code has to be dynamic because the columns and the rows can be changable.

```
k=4
for o in range(0,3):
    for p in range(0,k):
        df[f'w'{op}]=0
```

so in this case the columns that I have to generate have to be: w11, w12, w21, w22, w31, w32

output from the code above

```
  criterion 1 criterion 2 criterion 3  w
0        very        none      little  0
1      little        very        very  0
2        none        none        very  0
3        very        none        none  0
4        very        none      little  0
5        none        none      little  0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please paste in sample data and format as code along with expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `df[f'w'{op}]=0` seems wrong in the code snippet.

It should be written in the way like `df[f'w{o}{p}']=0`.

Try the below code sample and apply in your scenario,

```
# Create sample dataframe with shape (10,3)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(range(30)).reshape(10,3))

# Set the inputs as required in the column names and put it in loop

n_prefix = 3
n_suffix = 2

for pr in range(1,n_prefix+1):
    for sf in range(1,n_prefix+1):
        df[f"W{pr}{sf}"]= f"val{pr}_{sf}"

print(df.head(2))


0   1   2   W11     W12     W21     W22     W31     W32 
0   1   2   val1_1  val1_2  val2_1  val2_2  val3_1  val3_2
3   4   5   val1_1  val1_2  val2_1  val2_2  val3_1  val3_2
```